# actionlib callback based SimpleActionClient bind error

Tags: callback, boost, actionlib, actionlib-tutorials, simpleactionclient

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

so today I decided to write a callback based SimpleActionClient to get notified whenever a goal has finished.
I found [this](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Callback%20Based%20Simple%20Action%20Client) tutorial, but following the instructions will still give me errors. Please note: Using the SimpleActionClient the "normal" way works fine for me, but I need to change it to be callback based.

So basically, I have a class `MyNamespace::MyClass`. Then, when I want to send a goal, I use

```
client.sendGoal(goal, boost::bind(&MyNamespace::MyClass::doneCb, this, _1, _2));
```

With the `doneCb` class defined like in the tutorial:

```
void doneCb(const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState& state, const MyMessageActionResultConstPtr &result);
```

The error occurs at the line there I send the goal, it says, the template argument deduction/substitution failed.

Here some excerpt of the infinite error messages I get:

```
included from ...required from...stuff...
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:392: error: no match for call to '(boost::_mfi::mf2<void, MyNamespace::MyClass, const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const MyMessageActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&>) (MyNamespace::MyClass*&, const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const MyMessageResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&)'
     unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_], a[base_type::a3_]);
                              ^
included from ... required from... stuff...
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:299: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'MyNamespace::MyClass*' to 'MyNamespace::MyClass&'
```

I don't get what I did wrong, as I followed the example and tried multiple different cases of including and excluding the activeCb and feedbackCb, it all ends in similar errors.

Thank you for your support,

Marcel

Edit: more code and full error message:

More Code:

```
namespace(MyNamespace) {
class MyClass {
public:
MyClass () : client("action_name", true) { ... }
....
functionThatSendsGoal() {
MyMessageGoal goal;
// fill goal message, do stuff unrelated to client
```

client.sendGoal(goal, boost::bind(&MyNamespace::MyClass::doneCb, this, _1, _2)); //compile error occurs here
return;
}
doneCb(const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState& state, const MyMessageActionResultConstPtr &result) {
//do stuff
return;
}
protected:
actionlib::SimpleActionClient client;
...
};

MyMessage is actually a `control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectory` message.

Full Error Message, for those who can actually understand it:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/publisher.h:35,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45,
             from /home/marcel/ros/catkin_ws/src/project/src/MyNode.h:5,
             from /home/marcel/ros/catkin_ws/src/project/src/MyNode.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::_bi::list3<A1, A2, A3>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = boost::_mfi::mf2<void, MyNamespace::MyNode, const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&>; A = boost::_bi::list2<const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&>; A1 = boost::_bi::value<MyNamespace::MyClass*>; A2 = boost::arg<1>; A3 = boost::arg<2>]’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:102:59:   required from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(const A1&, const A2&) [with A1 = actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState; A2 = boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> > >; R = void; F = boost::_mfi::mf2<void, MyNamespace::MyClass, const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&>; L = boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<MyNamespace::MyClass*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> >; boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153:11:   required from ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker2<FunctionObj, R, T0, T1>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0, T1) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, MyNamespace::MyClass, const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<MyNamespace::MyClass*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >; R = void; T0 = const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:934:38:   required from ‘void boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, MyNamespace::MyClass, const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<MyNamespace::MyClass*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >; R = void; T0 = const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   required from ‘boost::function2<R, T1, T2>::function2(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, MyNamespace::MyClass, const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<MyNamespace::MyClass*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >; R = void; T0 = const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1069:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0, T1)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, MyNamespace::MyClass, const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<MyNamespace::MyClass*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> > >; R = void; T0 = const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&; T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/home/marcel/ros/catkin_ws/src/project/src/MyNode.cpp:374:140:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:392:34: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf2<void, MyNamespace::MyClass, const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&>) (MyNamespace::MyClass*&, const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
     unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_], a[base_type::a3_]);
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/prologue.hpp:18,
             from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:24,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/forwards.h:39,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/common.h:37,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:43,
             from /home/marcel/ros/catkin_ws/src/projcet/src/MyNode.h:5,
             from /home/marcel/ros/catkin_ws/src/project/src/MyNode.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:253:75: note: candidates are:
template<class R, class T, class A1, class A2 BOOST_MEM_FN_CLASS_F> class BOOST_MEM_FN_NAME(mf2)
                                                                       ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:215:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22,
             from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/prologue.hpp:18,
             from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:24,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/forwards.h:39,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/common.h:37,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:43,
             from /home/marcel/ros/project/src/MyNode.h:5,
             from /home/marcel/ros/project/src/MyNode.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:278:7: note: R boost::_mfi::mf2<R, T, A1, A2>::operator()(T*, A1, A2) const [with R = void; T = MyNamespace::MyClass; A1 = const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&; A2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&]
 R operator()(T * p, A1 a1, A2 a2) const
   ^
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:278:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> > >’ to ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&’
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:283:25: note: template<class U> R boost::_mfi::mf2<R, T, A1, A2>::operator()(U&, A1, A2) const [with U = U; R = void; T = MyNamespace::MyClass; A1 = const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&; A2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&]
 template<class U> R operator()(U & u, A1 a1, A2 a2) const
                     ^
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:283:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/publisher.h:35,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45,
             from /home/marcel/ros/project/src/MyNode.h:5,
             from /home/marcel/ros/project/src/MyNode.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:392:34: note:   cannot convert ‘(& a)->boost::_bi::list2<A1, A2>::operator[]<const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&>(boost::_bi::storage3<A1, A2, boost::arg<I> >::a3_<boost::_bi::value<MyNamespace::MyClass*>, boost::arg<1>, 2>)’ (type ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> > >’) to type ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&’
     unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_], a[base_type::a3_]);
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:215:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22,
             from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/prologue.hpp:18,
             from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:24,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/forwards.h:39,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/common.h:37,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:43,
             from /home/marcel/ros/project/src/MyNode.h:5,
             from /home/marcel/ros/project/src/MyNode.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:291:25: note: template<class U> R boost::_mfi::mf2<R, T, A1, A2>::operator()(const U&, A1, A2) const [with U = U; R = void; T = MyNamespace::MyClass; A1 = const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&; A2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&]
 template<class U> R operator()(U const & u, A1 a1, A2 a2) const
                     ^
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:291:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/publisher.h:35,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45,
             from /home/marcel/ros/project/src/MyNode.h:5,
             from /home/marcel/ros/project/src/MyNode.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:392:34: note:   cannot convert ‘(& a)->boost::_bi::list2<A1, A2>::operator[]<const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&, const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&>(boost::_bi::storage3<A1, A2, boost::arg<I> >::a3_<boost::_bi::value<MyNamespace::MyClass*>, boost::arg<1>, 2>)’ (type ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryResult_<std::allocator<void> > >’) to type ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&’
     unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_], a[base_type::a3_]);
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:215:0,
             from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22,
             from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/prologue.hpp:18,
             from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:24,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/forwards.h:39,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/common.h:37,
             from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:43,
             from /home/marcel/ros/project/src/MyNode.h:5,
             from /home/marcel/ros/project/src/MyNode.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:299:7: note: R boost::_mfi::mf2<R, T, A1, A2>::operator()(T&, A1, A2) const [with R = void; T = MyNamespace::MyClass; A1 = const actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState&; A2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult_<std::allocator<void> > >&]
 R operator()(T & t, A1 a1, A2 a2) const
   ^
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:299:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘MyNamespace::MyClass*’ to ‘MyNamespace::MyClass&’
make[2]: *** [project/CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/MyNode.o] Fehler 1
make[1]: *** [project/CMakeFiles/project.dir/all] Fehler 2
make: *** [all] Fehler 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195723/actionlib-callback-based-simpleactionclient-bind-error/) by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2014-10-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2014-10-23**:
Can you post more of your actual code (and errors) rather than just snippets? I suspect something you've cut would be helpful...

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2014-10-27**:
Hi kramer, I updated my post and added some more code and the full error message.I do not think, that more code would help, as it all happens at the line where I try to send my goal. But maybe someone can say what exactly is wrong by understanding these error messages...

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2014-10-27**:
I asked because I think you have transcription errors. For instance, in `doneCb`, 2nd parameter is `const MyMessageConstPtr &result`, but I think it needs to be `const MyMessageResultConstPtr &result`. Actual code is helpful; simplified code (often) is not.

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2014-10-27**:
As I'm sure you realize, the original (piece of the) error message you posted is helpful and where I'd start -- you're attempting to use a `MyNamespace::MyClass*` where it should be a `MyNamespace::MyClass&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to your comment, I figured it out:

I was using a

```
const MyMessageActionResultConstPtr &result
```

instead of

```
const MyMessageResultConstPtr &result
```

This at least got me rid of the previous compile error.

---

Originally posted by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) with karma: 200 on 2014-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2014-10-28**:
Well, that's...unexpected. But I'm glad to have helped.